# When I refresh a datagrid, the "selected values" don't change until the second click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a data grid, that when I select a line it will update two other data grids. It works well on initial load. But when I select the refresh button and reload the item source in MVVM model, the Selection Changed flag isn't tripped until after the second selection.

Visual Studio 2019, c#, WPF in MVVM format, using Dapper and Caliburn.Micro

ShellView Model: Button Logic

```
        public void BTN_RefreshHoldOrder()
        {
           CheckIfRefreshing = 1; 
           DG_HoldOrders.Clear();
           DG_HoldOrders = LoadDataGridHoldOrders();
 
            // Added these two lines to see if it would help the selected line value to auto change on first click       
           SelectedHoldOrder = DG_HoldOrders[0];
           SelectedHoldOrderIndex = 0;

// next 2 line manual reload of second table to get it to respond
            DG_Notes.Clear();
            DG_Notes = LoadDataGridNotes(SelectedOrderNoteId, SelectedCustNoteId, SelectedCustomerId, SelectedOrderNumber);

            CheckIfRefreshing = 1;

        }
```

This button reloads the DG_HoldOrders Bindable collection for the data grid.
The ShellView data grid is here

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DG_HoldOrders, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  Grid.Row="3" 
                  Grid.RowSpan="1"
                  Grid.Column="1" 
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedHoldOrder, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedHoldOrderIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  Name="DG_HoldOrder" Loaded="DG_HoldOrder_Loaded"
                  >
```

The selected value is pushed back to SelectedHoldOrder.
When that happens it updates the other data grids

```
 private HoldOrder _selectedHoldOrder = new HoldOrder();
public HoldOrder SelectedHoldOrder
        {
            get 
            { 
                return _selectedHoldOrder; 
            }
            set 
            { 
                _selectedHoldOrder = value;
               //var TestNotes = new BindableCollection<HoldOrder>();
                if (CheckIfRefreshing == 0)
                {
                                     
                    
                    if (SelectedHoldOrder.SOID.ToString() != null)
                    {

                        SelectedCustNoteId = SelectedHoldOrder.CustomerNoteId;
                        SelectedCustomerId = SelectedHoldOrder.CustomerID.ToString();
                        SelectedOrderNoteId = SelectedHoldOrder.OrderNoteId;
                        SelectedOrderNumber = SelectedHoldOrder.SONumber;

                        DG_Notes.Clear();

                        var TestNotes = LoadDataGridNotes(SelectedOrderNoteId, SelectedCustNoteId, SelectedCustomerId, SelectedOrderNumber);

                        DG_Notes = TestNotes;
                        SelectedNotesIndex = 0;

                        DG_Contacts.Clear();
                        DG_Contacts = LoadDataGridContacts(SelectedCustomerId);
                        SelectedContactIndex = 0;
                    }

                }
                
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>SelectedHoldOrder);
                CheckIfRefreshing = 0;
            }
        }
```

On initial load it works well. The initial index is preselected to 0. When select the next line the other two table refresh.  After I hit the refresh button. The index is reset to 0. I click the next line nothing happens. Then I click another line and everything refreshes properly. I then works until I click refresh again.  It looks like the selected value isn't properly set initially and that first flick sets it for the first time.  I want to try to keep this in the MVVM format and not use code behind if possible.

Answer (score 0):

adding IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true in the XAML. When true this will keep the Selected Item synchronized with the current item.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem?view=netcore-3.1

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DG_HoldOrders, Mode=OneWay}" 
              Grid.Row="3" 
              Grid.RowSpan="1"
              Grid.Column="1" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedHoldOrder, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedHoldOrderIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              Name="DG_HoldOrder" Loaded="DG_HoldOrder_Loaded"
              >
```

Comment: Thank you, I add the code and still has the same symptoms.

Comment: I think this is part of the solution, but now the child data grids do not populate when the page loads now. I'm still missing something.

Answer (score 0):

In the Refresh button logic I didn't turn off the Check If Refreshing option, so parts wouldn't run until the first click went through and reset the value.

```
CheckIfRefreshing = 1;

<refresh logic>

CheckIfRefreshing = 0;
```

The `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` logic made the issue worse so I took it out.